# Workflow in LIST to create new document in Library keeps erroring out

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, error

I have a list that contains simple single-line text fields.  I have created a workflow that, on the creation of new items, creates a document in a separate library (in the same site).  I have the workflow set up for list lookups for each column, so each column in the list is assigned to each column in the library.  However, every time the workflow runs, I get the error that states "Failed to create item. The workflow could not create the list item because the file name is either missing or invalid. "

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a pause/wait right after the line that creates the document. I had a similar problem where I was setting permissions and was getting the same error. The pause allows the system to catch up before going on to the next step in the workflow.